# combo of async map, recursion and callback in function- nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, callback

I have a function which computes a value and after the computation returns value with a callback to a another function.

The situation is starting to get pretty mixed where I have 2 nested for loops and recursion inside this.

Error is: `uncaughtException: Callback was already called.`

First let me write the sample of the code.

```
functionTest (array, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    nresponse.error(err);
  } else {
    nresponse.success(res, result);
  }
);

function dependicies(array, callback) {
    async.map(array, function(item, outerNext) {
        async.map(item.members, function(value, innerNext){
            dependicies(array, callback);
            innerNext(); //should I write this after or before the recursion call?
            outerNext(); //where should I call the outerNext?
        });

    }, function(err, result){
        **
        if(err){
            callback(err); 
        }else{
            callback(null, sthComputedInMap);
        }
    });
}
```

As I write in comments, should I write innerNext after or before the recursion call? In addition to the this question, should I call outerNext after the scope of second map?

Things are pretty messed. How am I gonna clear up? I'm looking the document.

** isn't this a place where it's the end of the first `async.map`. I think the problem is this is called for `each` `async.map` of the `recursion`. What I want is to call this as `break`.

In code I try to loop through an array. Assume I try to get list of name fields of one document's starting from itself to its last grand grand children.  The array's structure which I trace is like this;

```
[
  {id: 1, childrenIds: [3, 4, 5], name: ""},
  {id: 3, childrenIds: [8, 5], name: ""},
  {id: 21, childrenIds: [ 5], name: ""},
  {id: 7, childrenIds: [5], name: ""},
  {id: 5, childrenIds: [], name: ""}
 ]
```

first async.map is for traversing each document, the other one is for traversing its children array.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: It may help if you could let people know a little more about what you're trying to achieve, might just be me but I'm having a hard time getting my head around the recursion you mention, and maybe a little more context would help?

Comment: where does the recursion break in your code. I mean to say there should be a condition to so that it does not call dependencies() again and execute the next Callbacks.

Comment: @OliverRadini ok i will try. please wait of update.

Comment: @FarooqKhan i edited the question according to your comment.

Comment: @OliverRadini I added

Comment: This is still a little difficult to comprehend, perhaps because in your code you're referring to variables which are not defined here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix loops, recursion and callbacks using [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS). Below is a working example to illustrate. setTimeout is just used as an example of asynchronous function that returns result via callback.

```
global.SynJS = global.SynJS || require('synjs');

function processOneDoc(modules, documents, doc, childNames) {
    for(var i=0; doc.childrenIds && i < doc.childrenIds.length; i++) {
        var currDoc = documents[doc.childrenIds[i]];
        if(currDoc) {
            childNames.push(currDoc.name);
            var chNames=[];
            setTimeout(function(){
                SynJS.run(modules.processOneDoc, null, modules, documents, currDoc, chNames, function(){
                    SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
                });
                if(chNames.length)
                    childNames.push(chNames);
            },2000);
            SynJS.wait();
        }
    }
};

function processAll(modules, documents) {
    for(var d in documents) {
        var childNames=[];
        SynJS.run(modules.processOneDoc,null, modules, documents, documents[d], childNames,function(){
            SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
        });
        SynJS.wait();
        console.log(new Date().toISOString(), d, childNames);
    }
}

var modules = {
        SynJS:  SynJS,
        processOneDoc: processOneDoc,
};

var documents = {
                 1: {id: 1, childrenIds: [3, 4, 5], name: "name of 1st"},
                 3: {id: 3, childrenIds: [8, 5], name: "name of 3rd"},
                 21: {id: 21, childrenIds: [ 5], name: "name of 21st"},
                 7: {id: 7, childrenIds: [5], name: "name of 7th"},
                 5: {id: 5, childrenIds: [], name: "name of 5th"}
};

SynJS.run(processAll,null,modules,documents,function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

It would produce following output:

```
2017-01-06T18:50:57.750Z 1 [ 'name of 3rd', [ 'name of 5th' ], 'name of 5th' ]
2017-01-06T18:50:59.785Z 3 [ 'name of 5th' ]
2017-01-06T18:50:59.800Z 5 []
2017-01-06T18:51:01.831Z 7 [ 'name of 5th' ]
2017-01-06T18:51:03.863Z 21 [ 'name of 5th' ]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding for what you have provided in your question. Your recursion call is not on the right location. One way to solve your problem is as:

```
function dependencies(array, callback){
  outerResult = async.map(array, function(item, outerNext){
    var innerResult = async.map(item.members, function(value, innerNext){
     //recursive_call_condition == true
     // for instance you want to check if value has an array further
     if(value.members.length) 
         dependencies(value.members, callback);
     else
         innerNext(null, innerResult);
    });
    outerNext(null, outerResult);
  }, function(err, finalResult){
     // `finalResult` is your result
     callback(finalResult)
  });
}
```